# How to determine the local minimum of a multivariable function without using the derivatives?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-forms, quantum-mechanics

I have a multipole potential energy surface depending on 7 variables and I would like to determine the equilibrium position(minimum). The potential is on a sum-of-products of small functions so it is not easy to derivate.

I tried to determine the minimum by intervals but I did not get any satisfactory result.
<[potential formular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWNUm.jpg)>

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the function.

Answer (score 0):

Many numerical optimization packages can work without derivatives (or they have accompanying functions to create approximations of derivatives).

To look for a suitable package, you might start with [the Neos server](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html).